# How do you calculate the number density of air at 300K?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, density

I'm really new to this, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research efforts.

Comment: You should some effort from your side, take a look to ideal gas in wikipedia and change your question to more specific about the the details of the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

The density of air can be calculated from the ideal gas law
$$\rho_\textrm{air}(p,T)=\frac{p}{R_\textrm{ specific }T}$$
where $p$ is pressure in Pascal and $T$ temperature in Kelvin.

At $300^\circ ~\textrm{C}$ and $100~\textrm{kPa}\,,$ dry air has a density of $\rho_\mathrm{300k,1atm}=1.177~\mathrm{kg\cdot m^{-3}}$ ([source](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/dry-air-properties-d_973.html))

The average molar mass of air is $M_\textrm{avg} =28.97~\mathrm{g\cdot mol^{-1}}$ ([source](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/molecular-mass-air-d_679.html))

The number density is defined as 
$$n = \frac{N}{V} = \frac{N_a\cdot \textrm{mols}}{V}$$

This may be the tricky part, but dimensional analysis might be helpful
$$\frac{\rho}{M_\textrm{avg}}\equiv\mathrm{\frac{[kg]\cdot[m]^{-3}}{[g]\cdot [mol]^{-1}}\equiv10^{3}[mol]\cdot [m]^{-3}}$$
\begin{align}{n_\mathrm{300,1atm}}& = N_a\cdot \frac{\rho_\mathrm{300,1atm}}{M_\textrm{avg}}\cdot 10^3 \\&= 6.022\times 10^{23}\times\frac{1.177}{28.97}\times 10^3\\ &= 2.45\times 10^{25}~\mathrm{m^{-3}}\;.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit; it's 4am and I was lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

density = mass / volume 
so all you need to do is get your volume constant
find the volume of air @ 300 k then it is all the same

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Please either expand your answer by providing the full procedure or simply make it a comment below the question. This is poor for an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: The number density is the *number* of particles in a volume, so your answer is a little short of correct.